# How to get different text for each button in same column dynamically in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, button, datagridview, ado.net

I created a user control which has datagridview. Then I added row and column dynamically from textfile in datagridview.

My problem is I need column which has buttons in each row. In first row, the text of button is 'Test1' and in second row 'Test2' not the same text.

After searched on google I tried this code

```
var testButton = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
testButton.Name = "Test";
testButton.HeaderText = "Test";
testButton.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

testButton.Text = "Test1";
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(testButton);
```

But it gives me both button text as 'Test1'.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DatagridViewButtonColumn with different Text and different Functionality for different Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354700/datagridviewbuttoncolumn-with-different-text-and-different-functionality-for-dif)

Comment: Other similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166226/how-to-add-button-name-and-text-dynamically-to-gridview-button   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48430385/change-the-text-value-of-a-button-in-datagridviewbuttoncolumn

Comment: I have tried both question's solution. In first question's solution suggested to use CellFormatting and CellContentClick event. I tried both and same is suggested in Q2. But not yet got the result

Comment: `CellFormatting` should be enough. (`CellContentClick` is used there to change the button's behavior). It's weird that you didn't get the result. Can you show us an MCVE and explain what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: _ But not yet got the result _ That is not a helpful problem description!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in Windows Forms, you need to add a DataGridViewButtonColumn to your `DataGridView` - Not directly to the `DataTable`.

This should occur somewhere after you bind the `DataTable` to the `DataGridView`.

Something like this should work:

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn uninstallButtonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
uninstallButtonColumn.Name = "uninstall_column";
uninstallButtonColumn.Text = "Uninstall";
int columnIndex = 2;
if (dataGridViewSoftware.Columns["uninstall_column"] == null)
{
    dataGridViewSoftware.Columns.Insert(columnIndex, uninstallButtonColumn);
}
```

Of course you will have to handle the `CellClick` event of the grid to do anything with the button.

Add this somewhere in your `DataGridView` Initialization code

```
dataGridViewSoftware.CellClick += dataGridViewSoftware_CellClick;
```

Then create the handler:

```
private void dataGridViewSoftware_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridViewSoftware.Columns["uninstall_column"].Index)
    {
        //Do something with your button.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//Change the Button text property on a data-bound event 

    protected void YourDataGridViewId_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
       // finding the button control..`enter code here`.

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
           Button YourbtnVariable = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("YourbuttonID");
           YourbtnVariable.Text = "Text"+e.Row.RowIndex+1;
           //e.Row.RowIndex+1 will give u index of row every time incremented with 1
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation of your code so everyone can better understand it.